# OpenGL installed in Visual Studio Express but no GL control in toolbox

Tags: opentk

I have installed openGL into Visual Stuio Express 2015 from instructions on OpenTK. Looks like install was performed as there is new file OpenTK.DDL.config in solutions explorer in Moduel.VB. I tried to build and restart project but I still cannot get a GL Control icon in the toolbox. I also tried to add choose items for toolbox in .NET framework components but there are no options for openTK or GL components. Any ideas ? MY goal is to use 3D images and OpenTK seem to be the best way. I am programming in Basic and most other 3D viewer require C++.

Answer (score 0):

The GLControl package is not bundled with opentk itself for versions>=2.0. You should manually install glcontrol via nuget. 
After you've installed the package, build your project once (to let VS copy all .dll to your output directory), then you should be able to add glcontrol to the toolbox by "choose items->open file" from the newly copied .dll.

Comment: Can GLControl be used with Basic ?  I did not write in C# and looking to add the 3D viewer using Basic ?  Sorry for the long delay in responding

Comment: Opengl in its nature is not very suitable for Basic use, because there are lots of calls with *pointers*. You could use this control in vb.net but you may feel awkward.